# Knockout dropdown binding and returning value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am binding select list in knockout

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.Languages, optionsValue:function(item) { return item.Value; }, optionsText: function(item) {return item.Text; }, value: LanguageID, valueUpdate: 'change'" />
```

on submit ==>
var data = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel1);

Controller:

```
Languages = new SelectList(this.Languages(), "ID", "LanguageName", SelectedLanguageID);
```

It returns the complete object in 
LanguageID = "Selected: true, ID: 1, LanguageName: "English" 
but i want that it should return only ID like LanguageID = 1

I already use subscribe method and assign

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- Make sure that you properly open/close your `select` like:  `<select></select>`
- You can simplify your `optionsText` and `optionsValue` specifications by just passing the property name that you want as a string (`<select data-bind="options: Languages, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', value: LanguageID" ></select>`)
- You do not need to use `valueUpdate` on a select

Otherwise, it seems to be working properly.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dgmV6/